# Trouble Pairing Bluetooth Sound Bar with 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth

I am currently having issues pairing a *Yamaha YAS-103* sound bar with my system. It will appear in my Bluetooth manager screen however I can't seem to get it to pair. Using the `0000` Passkey fails as does the default pairing button.

The Bluetooth adapter being used is using an *Iogear GBU521W6* which was selected specifically because another thread listed it as working with Ubuntu "out of the box". A `lsusb` query comes up with the following result:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

A patcl list command provides this:

```
0   module-device-restore       
1   module-stream-restore       
2   module-card-restore     
3   module-augment-properties       
4   module-switch-on-port-available     
5   module-alsa-card    device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_06.1" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_06.1" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"    
6   module-alsa-card    device_id="1" name="pci-0000_07_00.1" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_07_00.1" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"    
7   module-udev-detect      
8   module-bluetooth-policy     
10  module-native-protocol-unix     
11  module-gconf        
12  module-default-device-restore       
13  module-rescue-streams       
14  module-always-sink      
15  module-intended-roles       
16  module-suspend-on-idle      
17  module-systemd-login        
18  module-position-event-sounds        
19  module-filter-heuristics        
20  module-filter-apply     
21  module-x11-publish  display=:0  
22  module-x11-bell display=:0 sample=bell.ogg  
23  module-x11-cork-request display=:0  
24  module-x11-xsmp display=:0 session_manager=local/TV:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1667,unix/TV:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1667    

0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_06.1.iec958-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED

1   alsa_output.pci-0000_07_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1 module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED

0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_06.1.iec958-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED

1   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_06.1.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED

2   alsa_output.pci-0000_07_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED

0   module-systemd-login.c  (null)

2   protocol-native.c   indicator-sound-service

3   protocol-native.c   unity-settings-daemon

7   module-x11-xsmp.c   (null)

8   protocol-native.c   python2.7

9   protocol-native.c   firefox

10  protocol-native.c   pactl

0   alsa_card.pci-0000_00_06.1  module-alsa-card.c

1   alsa_card.pci-0000_07_00.1  module-alsa-card.c
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The GBU521 uses a Broadcom bluetooth chip and might require firmware.  Please edit your question to include results in terminal of `lsusb`

Comment: The lsusb result has been added.

Comment: `sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` and see if it will pair.  Are you using Blueman?

Comment: That did it Jeremy thanks for the help. And in answer to your question I am using Blueman.

Comment: You might want to check `pactl list short` for `module-bluetooth-discover` after a reboot as some versions of Blueman will unload it

Answer (score 0):

Check `pactl list short` for `module-bluetooth-discover` as it is needed for A2DP sound over bluetooth.  Some versions of Blueman are known to remove it during boot.

You can load `module-bluetooth-discover` with

```
sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Then pair with the device and A2DP will work

If you want or need HSP/HFP also then you need the firmware

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7xdswqav8nqfr1/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd
sudo cp BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Jeremy. I gave it a try but no dice. Are there any other logs that I can provide that might narrow the problem down?

Comment: Post the result from 'pactl list short`

Comment: Added to the initial post.

Comment: @Jeremy31 Could you please edit your answer so that it is more clear which command solved the problem and when or why it is necessary to load the firmware? Your answer should include all the information needed.