# Ubuntu 15.10 - USB Bluetooth not working

Tags: usb, 15.10, bluetooth

I have looked at some other answers already, none of them seemed applicable or fixed anything.

I have USB Bluetooth on 15.10. It used to work fine. I went to pair my headphones today and noticed I couldn't turn Bluetooth on.

**Service Status**

```
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth -l

bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-03-20 23:09:56 EDT; 3min 8s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
  Process: 1847 ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 1847 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Mar 20 23:09:56 brian-htpc systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Mar 20 23:09:56 brian-htpc systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Mar 20 23:09:56 brian-htpc systemd[1]: Failed to start Bluetooth service.
Mar 20 23:09:56 brian-htpc systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 20 23:09:56 brian-htpc systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**lsusb**

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
```

**rfkill**

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**dmesg**

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    3.200940] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    3.200957] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.200963] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.200966] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.200973] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.220752] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[    3.223753] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[    3.369865] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd failed with error -2
[    3.369875] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd not found
```

So it seems the driver or firmware for it is missing for some reason. How do I reinstall it? Is there an apt package that takes care of this?

I have tried `find`/`locate` on `BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd` and wildcard variations to see if maybe it was just in the wrong place, and that does not seem to be the case - I believe it was deleted at some point, somehow.

**UPDATES**

As per **P.H. Lin** and **Jeremy31**'s comments:

- Installing the firmware from the other thread did not fix my problem, and `lsusb` no longer detected a BT unit. `hciconfig -a` did not return any output.
- I removed the firmware file (`*.hcd`) rebooted and my BT unit appeared again on `lbusb`, with the result of `sudo hciconfig -a` being:

```
$ sudo hciconfig -a

hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 5C:F3:70:77:02:F7  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:616 acl:0 sco:0 events:34 errors:0
    TX bytes:380 acl:0 sco:0 commands:34 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'BCM20702A'
    Class: 0x000000
    Service Classes: Unspecified
    Device Class: Miscellaneous, 
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x1000
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x220e
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
```

However the unit still does not "work" so I am back where I started it would seem.

Comment: This thread worth a try [Trouble Pairing Bluetooth Sound Bar with 14.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/645239/trouble-pairing-bluetooth-sound-bar-with-14-04-lts/645263#645263)

Comment: @P.-H.Lin thanks for the comment. I tried the steps in that thread, and installing the `.hcd` into `/lib/firmware/brcm/` ended up removing the BT adapter from the `lsusb` command! :(

Comment: Please edit question to include `hciconfig -a`  The firmware on this chip is only needed for HFP/HSP low quality audio

Comment: @Jeremy31 thank you for the help. I have updated the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed my own issue by simply reinstall the BT stack (bluez) via apt.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bluez
```

So there you have it - if your BT device is detected and seems to be working properly but just isn't showing up, try reinstalling the bluetooth stack.

Comment: So now it works with your headsets?

Comment: @P.-H.Lin Yes it's working fine again.

Answer (score 2):

If someone else stumbles upon this, I had/have a similar problem.
For whatever reason, on my system

```
/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

is not executable, and thus it obviously fails to start.

So,

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

fixes the problem, at least until the next reboot. Reinstalling bluex fixes it as well - though I have not rebooted yet, so I don't know if it will survive the reboot.